# Print Pandas DataFrame using letters as column index (as in MS Excel) instead of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm using Pandas to read a MS Excel .xlsx file, so far this is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

excel_file = 'test.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheetname='Sheet2', header=None)
print(df)
```

And the output is:

```
   0  1  2
0  5  6  7
1  8  9  0
[Finished in 0.8s]
```

Instead, I would like to see it as in MS Excel:

```
   A  B  C
0  5  6  7
1  8  9  0
[Finished in 0.8s]
```

I mean column index should be letters. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Considering your dataframe to be this:

```
In [184]: df
Out[184]: 
   0  1  2
0  5  6  7
1  8  9  0
```

If you have a small number of columns, you can directly do this:

```
df.columns = ['A','B','C']
```

**OR**

If the number of columns is much more, do this:

You can use create a list with alphabets and assign it to `df.columns`:

```
In [189]: col_list = [ chr(i+65) for i in range(len(df.columns)) ]
In [190]: col_list
Out[190]: ['A', 'B', 'C']

In [191]: df.columns = col_list

In [192]: df
Out[192]: 
   A  B  C
0  5  6  7
1  8  9  0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need up to Z, you can use:

```
df = df.rename(columns={i:chr(i+65) for i in range(26)})
```